# How to add common code (specifically to methods marked WebMethod())

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I have some ASP.NET page and webservice WebMethod() methods that I'd like to add some common code to.  For example:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function AddressLookup(ByVal zipCode As String) As Address
    #If DEBUG Then
        ' Simulate a delay
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
    #End If
    Return New Address()
End Function
```

I currently have the #If Debug code in all of my WebMethod() methods, but I am thinking there must be a better way to do this without having to actually type the code in.

Is there a way to determine if a request is to a WebMethod in Application_EndRequest so that I can add this delay project wide?

Note that some methods are Page methods and some are web service methods.

Comment: I am looking into PostSharp as well to see if that might achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the request URL in Application_EndRequest to determine whether it is a web method call. E.g. something like this (sorry it's in C#):

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf("MyWebService.asmx") > 0)
  {
    // Simulate a delay
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's good... see my edit though: Some methods are PageMethods and some are from a web service, so the asmx search won't catch everything.  I should have specified that from the get go.

Comment: Maybe split the page methods and web service methods into two web services? Then you can check the URL for "MyWebService.asmx". Otherwise I guess Mehrdad's approach might be better.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate the `#if DEBUG` code in a method and mark it with `<Conditional("DEBUG")>`. This way, you just write a method call in each `<WebMethod>`. Might be useful.